# Get custom attribute in one step checkout

Tags: magento2.3, xml, knockoutjs

I'm trying to get a custom attribute (mgs_brand) in MagePlaza's One Step Checkout.

I've created a catalog_attributes.xml file like so -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="mgs_brand"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

Added this code to my details.js -

```
getBrand: function (parent) {
                console.log("details.js starts here");
                var itemProduct = this.getItemProduct(parent.item_id);
                return itemProduct.mgs_brand;
},
```

Added this to my details.html -

```
<!-- ko if: (getBrand($parent))-->
       <strong class="product-item-brand" data-bind="text:getBrand($parent)"></strong>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The closest I've managed to get is a value in the window.checkoutConfig object, but it's an ID rather than the actual attribute value.

Am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding your value in `CompositeConfigProvider`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
       <arguments>
           <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="mgs_brand" xsi:type="object">Namespace\ModuleName\Model\AdditionalConfigVars</item>
           </argument>
       </arguments>
   </type>
</config>
```

> /app/code/Namespace/Modulename/Model/AdditionalConfigVars.php

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model;

use \Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface

class AdditionalConfigVars implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
   public function getConfig()
   {
       $additionalVariables['mgs_brand'] = 'Test Var';
       return $additionalVariables;
   }
}
```